# Problems with the build in Travis CI in the file search master.xml via Liquibase

Tags: java, travis-ci

Please tell me. My project is built locally with no problems. But Travis CI gets an error in the build:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.2.2:update (default) on project: 

[ERROR] Error setting up or running Liquibase:
[ERROR] The file /home/travis/build/.../src/db/master.xml was not found in
[ERROR]     - /home/travis/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar...
```

also even lower: [ERROR]     - /home/travis/build//target/test-classes

```
[ERROR] Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter.
```

I had a similar error locally, but for a different file, `master.xml` where the path to `<include file="src/db/scripts/update_001.sql"/>` is written - I fixed it, so the project is being built locally. But in Travis, it looks like a similar error, but for the file, `master.xml`.

Settings in the file `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/db/master.xml</changeLogFile>
        <url>${db.url}</url>
        <driver>${db.driver}</driver>
        <username>${db.username}</username>
        <password>${db.password}</password>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>update</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The path is spelled out correctly:

```
<changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/db/master.xml</changeLogFile>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you checked out this article? https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/liquibase-relative-path-best-practices.html

It seems Liquibase 4.0 and later versions doesn’t allow specifying absolute paths.  Instead, use paths relative directories included in your classpath.

Comment: yes, this is just related to the path. I just installed an older version and everything was fine